# Install PEAR with Wamp 2.1

Tags: php, installation, wamp, wampserver, pear

I want to install PEAR on my windows 7. I have Wamp 2.1 with php 5.3.4
It seems that there's no such files as "go-pear.bat" in this new version of wamp.

Then how can I install PEAR ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an older version of PHP on your machine? I noticed I have PEAR in my 5.3.0 version: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR. I don't know if my 5.3.4 uses it or if not, could I copy it to the 5.3.4 folder. . . Just thoughts that may help.

Comment: http://www.google.de/search?q=go-pear

Comment: I'd like to know how to install it with php 5.3.4 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the [PEAR installation instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) on the PEAR website. And yes, you can follow the Unix steps to get a `go-pear.phar` file.

Comment: i have the same problem...using the current go-pear.phar file says my PHP version v 5.3.4 is too new :( Any updated version for go-pear.phar?

Answer (score 5):

I have followed these steps and it works for me
1. download go-pear.phar right from pear website. http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
2. Copy this file in c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8
3. Open command promt.
4. Go to the php5.3.8 directory using cd c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8
5. run the command php go-pear.phar

Thanks

Comment: @user1153966 I get: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to alloca
te 91 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 91
 bytes) in Unknown on line 0