# PHP error on installin pear on windows xp

Tags: php, windows-xp, installation, pear, wampserver

Hello I am using [Wamp Server 2.0](http://www.wampserver.com/) and trying to instal [pear](http://pear.php.net/). When I run the go-pear.bat it gives me these errors. [Here is the complete install process output](http://pastebin.com/fiq6riX2)

Thank you for all your helps

Comment: Are you logged in as administrator? Are you inside the PHP program directory?

Comment: Probably this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994095/install-pear-with-wamp-2-1

Comment: Yes I am logged in as administrator. Yes it is related in someway but I dont use Windows 7.

Comment: Have you read the [pear installation instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the new PEAR 1.9.4 that has just been released, with some issues fixed that sound like yours.